# How to print newline when it find \n in a string variable value?

Tags: java, string

Good Morning,

I had a string value like

```
 Name:Anilbabu\nPlace:Pamarru\nAge::22\n
```

while printing that string variable.. I don't want to see "\n" in output, Instead, I want to have new line printed like,

```
 Name:Anilbabu
 Place:Pamarru
 Age:22
```

Please help me friends, Please give solution in Java.

Thank you.

Comment: `Please give solution in Java.` ?? Sure. What you tried so far.?

Comment: I didn't try anything till now.. I had seen StringBuffer.. but it is not useful in my case..

Answer (score 2):

Use StringTokenizer

```
StringTokenizer strings = new StringTokenizer(input, "\\n");
while (strings.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(strings.nextToken());
}
```

OR

use :

```
System.out.print(input.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
String str = "Name:Anilbabu\nPlace:Pamarru\nAge::22\n"; // the String.
System.out.print(str);                                  // Print the String
```

Outputs

```
Name:Anilbabu
Place:Pamarru
Age:22
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
String input = "Name:Anilbabu\nPlace:Pamarru\nAge::22\n";
String[] result = input.split("[\\n]");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(result[i]);         
}
```

**Output**

```
Name:Anilbabu
Place:Pamarru
Age::22
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit too complicated when the `String` could just be printed?

Comment: @Quincunx I thought so.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the value

```
System.out.println("Name:Anilbabu\nPlace:Pamarru\nAge::22\n");
```

or Assign it to a variable and then print

```
String st ="Name:Anilbabu\nPlace:Pamarru\nAge::22\n";
System.out.println(st);
```